# How can we update the multiple ids which are in csv file in python script?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to update the table based on id. I have multiple ids more than 1.4 million. So I have kept the 1.4 million ids in one CSV file and in my code using chunks. As of now I have kept 10 records in my CSV file for testing. But my update query is not working. in the id values passing like id = '3    a6P3a0000058StwEAE.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


DF = pd.read_csv("/home/bha/harddeleteid10.csv", names=['colm_id'], header=None)

def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq [pos:pos + size] for pos in range (0, len(seq), size))

for i in chunker(DF['colm_id'],3):
    engine = create_engine("db", echo=True)
    conn = engine.connect()
    conn.autocommit = True
    conn.execute(f"""update salesforce_fr.apttus_proposal__proposal_line_item__c_poc set isdeleted=True where id = '{i}'""")
```

Below is id passing in query from the above loop(i is in series datatype).

```
update salesforce_fr.apttus_proposal__proposal_line_item__c_poc set isdeleted=True where id = '6    a6P3a0000057TGuEAM
```

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not understood globally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is with the textual SQLAlchemy statement. It does not follow the sqlalchemy textual SQL recommendations.

Replace this

```
conn.execute(f"""update salesforce_fr.apttus_proposal__proposal_line_item__c_poc set isdeleted=True where id = '{i}'""")
```

With this

```
    # build a sqlalchemy statement using textual SQL
    statement = text("update salesforce_fr.apttus_proposal__proposal_line_item__c_poc set isdeleted=True where id = (:x)")
    statement.bindparams(x=i)
    conn.execute(statement)
```

There was a lot of extra code in your example. I hope this helps.